# Fileupload in CreateUserWizard

Tags: createuserwizard

I have a createuserwizard (cuw) control and I want to add more fields (customizing). I need to store this info in a database called 'UserProfiles'. I´ve added a fileupload control to store an image (avatar) and the problem is here. When I refresh my database (after I filled the cuw control) I can see the new data for all the columns, EXCEPT for the image column. I supose the problem is in the code behind. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateUserProfile(CreateUserWizard1.UserName, txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, CreateUserWizard1.Email, CreateUserWizard1.Password, imgUpload.FileName);
}

private void CreateUserProfile(string UserName, string Gender, string LookingFor, string Email, string Password, string Image)
{
    string conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserProfiles"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT UserProfiles (UserName,Gender,LookingFor,EMail,Password,Image) VALUES (@UserName,@Gender,@LookingFor,@EMail,@Password,@Image)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Gender);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LookingFor", LookingFor);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMail", Email);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", Image);
    using (con)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
}
```

I´m a beginner. Thanks in advance for your help.